# How do I make a Output Label on Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, label

I am new at using Visual Studio as well as C#. I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to make a output label. Does anyone know how to do this?

What I've currently been doing is dragging the label control to the text box. Then, I would delete the text from the label but then it looks like it disappeared .

Comment: what do you exactly want? give an example

Comment: i'll try to explain the best I can.  I have a textbox that is used to enter your name. By  pressing a button (input button)  obtained from the toolbox, the name show up on the output label. Unfortunately I don't know how to make an output label.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all: this is broad question! I'll just answer according to my understanding.

Define the `AutoSize` of your `label` to `False`, then you can erase its text (`label1.Text = String.Empty`) without the label being seen as if it disappeared

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is what you want,

```
System.Windows.Forms.Label label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
label1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(34, 49);
label1.Name = "label1";
label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(85, 23);
label1.TabIndex = 0;
label1.Text = "label1";
label1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
```